# Using call_user_func() with "parent::" and "self::"

Tags: php, php-5.3

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Changelog, 5.3.0:

> The interpretation of object oriented keywords like parent and self has changed. Previously, calling them using the double colon syntax would emit an E_STRICT warning because they were interpreted as static.

I am using the PHP 7.x and I understand that this is no longer the issue. But lets assume that we are back at using the PHP version prior to the 5.3.0, something like 5.2.0 (if there was something like that). What was the problem with using the "parent::" and "self::" and why this was producing the warning. I was thinking calling a non-static method statically, but how would the call_user_func() assume that the called method was non-static. I just cant imagine what this Changelog note means.

Thanks.

Comment: PHP 5.3 introduced [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php). This it the reason of the paragraph you quoted.

Comment: *"something like 5.2.0 (if there was something like that)"* -- curious about the PHP version numbers (and when they were released and ended their lifes)? Check the [list of previous versions](http://php.net/eol.php) and the [list of currently supported and developed versions](http://php.net/supported-versions.php).

Comment: 1) So previously we would be using "parent::" and "self::" and this would be interpreted as static? Is it not a static call 100% of the time? It can be interpreted as static and somethig else (I guess the dynamic)? 2) They were interpreted as static and this was wrong? Why? Calling a non-static function statically I was assuming, but how would we know that the called method is non-static? Like I said, I dont understand.

Comment: What was the problem with using the "parent::" and "self::" and why this was producing the warning. Answer: The problem was a bug in the function argument parser. My comment: If possible, any additional info would be great as this is somehow hard to understand (for me, still). Thanks.